# Segment fault. Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am pretty new to C++ but I kinda got to solve this problem. It will be really really appreciated if you can help me to do.

It is a kind of cron program which run once a day and it worked well until today. But it showed me a segment fault. It gets user information from mysql and make some match by city and insert into a table on the mysql.  so I ran valgrind to get some more information as below.

```
==11897== Invalid read of size 1  
==11897==    at 0x4C28F52: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:403)  
==11897==    by 0x5BF614B: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)  
==11897==    by 0x4039E7: insertMatchByCity(st_mysql*, std::string) (main.cpp:156)  
==11897==    by 0x407DB5: main (main.cpp:759)  
==11897==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

AND this as well

```
==11897== LEAK SUMMARY:  
==11897==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==11897==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==11897==      possibly lost: 321,326 bytes in 9,167 blocks  
==11897==    still reachable: 609,929 bytes in 1,886 blocks  
==11897==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==11897== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.  
==11897== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes  
==11897==   
==11897== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)  
==11897==   
==11897== 1 errors in context 1 of 9:  
==11897== Invalid read of size 1  
==11897==    at 0x4C28F52: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:403)  
==11897==    by 0x5BF614B: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)  
==11897==    by 0x4039E7: insertMatchByCity(st_mysql*, std::string) (main.cpp:156)  
==11897==    by 0x407DB5: main (main.cpp:759)  
==11897==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd  
==11897==   
--11897--   
--11897-- used_suppression:      4 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object  
--11897-- used_suppression:      2 glibc-2.5.x-on-SUSE-10.2-(PPC)-2a  
==11897==   
==11897== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)  
Segmentation fault
```

and the other part of the msg showed me that source code below need revised

```
    //get open city list
    vector<string> cityList;

  sql = "SELECT distinct cityname FROM citylist WHERE open=1";

    if(mysql_query(conn,sql.c_str())){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }

    res = mysql_store_result(conn);

    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))!=NULL){
        cityList.push_back(row[0]);
    }
    mysql_free_result(res);

    //match according city
    while(cityList.size()>0){
        string city = cityList[cityList.size()-1];
        insertMatchByCity(conn,city);
        cityList.erase(cityList.end()-1);
    }
```

Anyone who understand this well. give me easy direction please?

Thanks you very much in advance

Comment: Errors without the code that produced that error are only half the story.

Comment: Wild guess. Do you do something like this: `std::string s = 0;`?

Comment: Which line is 759 in main.cpp?

Comment: @jrok insertMatchByCity(conn,city);    is the line 759.

Comment: I suspect this: `row[0]` can contain a null pointer, invoking my "wild guess" error above.

Comment: Probably not the source of your problem, but `cityList[cityList.size()-1];` is more idiomaticaly written as `citylist.back()`. Likewise, `cityList.erase(cityList.end()-1);` should be `cityList.pop_back();`.

Comment: Is it a multi-threaded process? from the logs you've shared, problem is arising because process is trying to dereference a null pointer. Why don't you run the above query "SELECT distinct cityname FROM citylist WHERE open=1" and see if any cityname  is returned as NULL

Comment: Very likely that you have a malloc or new which has failed (given you a null pointer) and somehow the code does not check for that.  The reason why is startes failing now is likely due to some changes in system settings where you process is allowed less memory.

Comment: @sanjayk79 the city name is all filled well and the code worked well until last night..

Comment: Is it multi-threaded?

Comment: @Brianc What does the insertMatchBytCity() look like? Since according to your valgrind printout something goes wrong inside that function  it would be appropriate to show the code.

Comment: @sanjayk79 yes. I can get the city name by getting the name of university.

Comment: read my probable root cause of the issue in answers section

Answer (score 1):

There's very small amount of code to guess, but, here's what I think:

```
while(cityList.size()>0){
    string city = cityList[cityList.size()-1];
    insertMatchByCity(conn,city);
    cityList.erase(cityList.end()-1);
}
```

If you are sending out city to insertMatchByCity by reference (may be to another thread), and that thread has still not processed its data i.e. it is still holding reference to city. Lets say that thread gets preempted by OS.
Now, your iteration (while loop) will continue and city which is a local scoped variable will be destroyed. 
So, now when that thread tries to de-reference city, it results in a crash!

Applying my forensic analysis :)

Comment: thanks for your advice. but it worked flawlessly until last night. do you think some change on the system may affected the running?

Comment: These are called race conditions and can crop up anytime. I've seen systems running for couple of years before crashing miserably. I've a hunch that the root cause I specified is the culprit. In such a case change     

    insertMatchByCity(conn,city); 
 
to accept city as value, not reference

Answer (score 0):

**I think this may be your problem:**

```
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))!=NULL){
    cityList.push_back(row[0]);
}
```

According to the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-row.html) your `row[0]` can contain a `null` pointer. That means when you push it back onto your vector of strings a `std::string` is initialized with a null pointer. Legal, but a fatal error.

**Maybe try something like this?**

```
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))!=NULL){
    if(row[0])
        cityList.push_back(row[0]); // if you don't want blank items
}
```

**Or this:**

```
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))!=NULL){
    cityList.push_back(row[0] ? row[0] : ""); // if blank items are ok
}
```

Comment: really appreciate your advice but both code did not work I am afraid.

Comment: try adding a fprintf(stderr, "row[0]=%p\n", row[0]); to the beginning of your loop -- that way if you see it print out row[0]=0 just before the crash, you know that a NULL pointer is your problem.

Comment: @Brianc can you point out which line is exhibiting the error?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I added the code and it showed 
row[0]=0xa18b48
row[0]=0xa18b78 
row[0]=0xa18ba8 
row[0]=0xa18bd8 
row[0]=0xa18c08 
row[0]=0xa18c38 
row[0]=0xa18c68 
row[0]=0xa18c98 
row[0]=0xa18cc8  
row[0]=0xa18d00 
row[0]=0xa18d30 
row[0]=0xa18d60 
row[0]=0xa18d90

Comment: @Brianc I meant which line in your original code. If we know what line is triggering the fail it will help in deducing the cause.